# How to get the user control textbox value in aspx page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a User control ascx file with a textbox in it

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textboxDate" runat="server" CssClass="FieldValue" MaxLength="10"
Columns="12" autocomplete="off" Style="padding-right: 18px; border: 1px solid #567890;" />
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="calendarExtenderDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="textboxDate"
PopupButtonID="textboxDate" />
```

I'm adding this user control in my aspx page

```
  <uc:DateControl ID="dateControlStart" runat="server" RequiredErrorMessage="please enter date" />
```

and i want the value of this textbox . How can i do this using javascript or Jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below

```
$("input[id*=textboxDate]").val();
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, it is working can u explain this why when we write $('#textboxDate').val() the value does not come and how come this is working

Comment: It is because in webforms the id will get changed with the name from masterpage and will autoID and so if we check the element with id contains "*=" we will get the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a **public property** in the user control to access the text box.

Example:

**In User Control code behind**

```
 public TextBox MyTextBox{
  get{return this.textboxDate;}

 }
```

**In Page code behind**

```
dateControlStart.MyTextBox.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

Since .NET creates it's own id's for controllers it's a bit problematic. But there's 2 ways around this.

1, create a containing div with an `id`.

```
// HTML
<div id="date-container">
    //.. .NET controllers
</div>

// Script
var container = document.getElementById('date-container'),
    input = container.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

console.log(input.value);
```

2, Add and unique css class to you asp:textbox and use jQuery to retrive it:

```
$('.date-input-unique').val();
```